# KnockoutJS Validation plugin doesn't show error message

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I try to use KnockoutJs [validation plugin](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation) and I have a problem. Before post data from input I validate the value, if it is correct I post it and reset my viewmodel to the default state, if value isn't correct I wrap the input into the red border by adding some css class (or add error message). The problem is that this works only once: after post data I reset my viewmodel to the default state (as I said before), the input field becomes empty and if I try to post this empty data, validation works, but css class doesn't apply (error message doesn't appear). Please try my [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SamousPrime/dhYVZ/), what's wrong ?

* [Update].

So, I found workaround: just add additional code to data-bind attribute

```
validationElement: itemToAdd().Name
```

it should be

```
<input data-bind='value: itemToAdd().Name, validationElement: itemToAdd().Name' />
```

It works, but looks bad. Anyway, it will be good, if someone can fix my previous code.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
var t = ko.validation.group(viewModel.itemToAdd())
```

to

```
var t = ko.validation.group(viewModel.itemToAdd)
```

Comment: But in this case the value into input field won't be cleared after click on button.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/dhYVZ/23/) exemplifying my answer.

One way to approach this is to have your `activeAccount` object have a property, I called mine `errors`, that would hold all the validation messages for that object.

```
var activeAccount = function(data) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.name).extend({ required: { message: 'Enter account name.'} });
    this.UserId = ko.observable(1);
    this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
};

var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([]), 
    itemToAdd: ko.observable(new activeAccount({})),
    createItem: function (item) {
        if (item.errors().length == 0) {
            viewModel.items.push(item);
            viewModel.itemToAdd(new activeAccount({}));
        } else {
            item.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    }
};
```

Once you've saved the item (whether it's posting to the server, pushing to an observableArray or both) you then "reset" `itemToAdd` by setting it to a `new activeAccount({})` by passing an empty object to the constructor.